# How to add filters to a custom entity type listing page

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity type and a list of entities of that types shown on a standard listing page.

[image: screenshot 1]

But I need to have some filters similar to what we have on a node list page

[image: screenshot 2]

How could I do that ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the views module?

Comment: Could so, but seems not really. I don't see any way of using it for admin pages in D8

Comment: You can create a views list page for your entity type. P.S> if you'll use the same path as your current list page, it will override it.

Comment: How would I do that ?

Comment: I don't know why the answer was deleted. It was actually the correct, related answer, just a bit short. The node list is a view. The by far easiest option is to add views integration by specifying the views_data handler on the entity type, see examples in core and create a view.

Comment: examples of code in core in which mod for instance ? Went through node but didn't notice where the magic is happening

Comment: The simplest way is create a view like "Content View"
More information can be found in `/admin/structure/views/view/content` Another way, you can create a form expose for that EntityListBuilder

Answer (score 2):

Yes, everybody keeps mentioning Views. But it can be done easily without Views.

Basically, you need, in addition to your `EntityListBuilder`, a form that will expose the filter. Just create a usual form extending `FormBase`, building whatever UI you need (eg. a dropdown with items to select from, and a **Filter** submit button).

Your list builder will first create that form and then use it together with the rendered entity list:

```
public function render() {
  $build['form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\your_module\Form\YourFilterForm');
  $build += parent::render();
  return $build;
}
```

In the submit handler of the form, you redirect to the same URL but with the filter query variables added:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $value = $form_state->getValue('your_var_name');
  $query = ['your_var_name' => $value];
  $form_state->setRedirect('route_name_of_your_entity_list', $query);
}
```

Also, if you want a **Reset** button, just do the same redirect without the query, thus clearing it.

In your entity list builder, you have a `getEntityIds()` that's responsible for loading the entities. You probably didn't override it at all to get the full list. But you can override, get the current filter and only load those matching the filter:

```
protected function getEntityIds() {
  $value = \Drupal::request()->get('your_var_name');
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery($this->entityTypeId);
  $query->condition('your_var_name', $value);
  return $query->execute();
}
```

Or, if there is no actual filter, just call the original `parent::getEntityIds();`.